# Sql Islands and Gaps Merge Contiguous records if relevant fields hold same values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a test case here for my problem https://rextester.com/ZRXSQ14415

Its must each easier to show the problem to explain what I am trying to achieve.

I have a list of records across time and I wish to merge contiguous records into a single record.

Each record has a period Date, Risk Levels and a couple of flags.   When these risks and flags are the same the records should be merged when they are different then they should be a separate row.

On the Rextester example, i have almost achieved my goal, however look at rows 3 + 4 of the result.

What I want to achieve is that rows 3 + 4 would be combined such that row 3

```
StartDate   End Date    Name     ... ...
17.03.2019  20.03.2019  CPWJ40-A ... ...
```

As all flags and risk levels are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Change the SEQ expression to

```
..
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PeriodDate) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY ImplicitRisk,QCReadyRisk,IsQualityControlReady,   ActivePeriod ORDER BY PeriodDate) AS SEQ
..
```

This way you'll get the proper grouping of islands of  `ImplicitRisk,QCReadyRisk,IsQualityControlReady,   ActivePeriod`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is purely to complement Serg answer with the full query.

```
SELECT MIN(d.PeriodDate) AS StartDate,
       MAX(d.PeriodDate) AS EndDate,
       ImplicitRisk,
       QcReadyRisk,
       IsQualityControlReady,
       ActivePeriod,
       LocationEventName
FROM
(
    SELECT c.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PeriodDate) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY LocationEventId, ImplicitRisk, QCReadyRisk, IsQualityControlReady, ActivePeriod ORDER BY PeriodDate) AS grp
    FROM   tab c
    --order by PeriodDate
    ) d
group by ImplicitRisk, QcReadyRisk, IsQualityControlReady, ActivePeriod, LocationEventName, grp
order by 1
```

Comment: I would say this answer is correct because you point out that a subquery is necessary.  Just changing the `row_number()` calculation doesn't affect the aggregation.